# Python/Pandas: Unexpected indices when doing a groupby-apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas and Numpy on Python3 with the following versions:

- Python 3.5.1 (via Anaconda 2.5.0) 64 bits
- Pandas 0.19.1
- Numpy 1.11.2 (probably not relevant here)

Here is the minimal code producing the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame({'i' : [1,1,1,1,1], 'a': [1,2,5,6,100], 'b': [2, 4,10, np.nan, np.nan]})
a.set_index(keys='a', inplace=True)
v = a.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(by='i')['b'].rolling(2, min_periods=0).mean())
v.index.names
```

This code is a simple groupby-apply, but I don't understand the outcome:

```
FrozenList(['a', 'a'])
```

For some reason, the index of the result is ['a', 'a'], which seems to be a very doubtful choice from pandas. I would have expected a simple ['a'].

Does anyone have some idea about why Pandas chooses to duplicate the column in the index?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's because of the call to `sort_values` this returns a new df so the index is being concatenated with the existing `groupby` index, you could argue that it shouldn't do this but normally it's expecting a scalar value to be returned, as a Series or DataFrame is being returned it looks like it's aligning and concatenating here

Comment: What are you trying to group by? Within your `a.groupby()` you should have the parameter `as_index=False`

Comment: @A.Kot you would get `[None, 'a']` for the index names here when you pass `index=False` I think the OP is querying why there is are 2 levels of indices here, as well as the duplication of the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `sort_values` returns a DataFrame or Series so the index is being concatenated to the existing groupby index, the same thing happens if you did `shift` on the 'b' column:

```
In [99]:
v = a.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['b'].shift())
v

Out[99]:
a    a  
1    1     NaN
2    2     NaN
5    5     NaN
6    6     NaN
100  100   NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

even with `as_index=False` it would still produce a multi-index:

```
In [102]:
v = a.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x['b'].shift())
v

Out[102]:
   a  
0  1     NaN
1  2     NaN
2  5     NaN
3  6     NaN
4  100   NaN
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

if the lambda was returning a plain scalar value then no duplicating index is created:

```
In [104]:
v = a.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x['b'].max())
v

Out[104]:
a
1       2.0
2       4.0
5      10.0
6       NaN
100     NaN
dtype: float64
```

I don't think this is a bug rather some semantics to be aware of that some methods will return an object where the index will be aligned with the pre-existing index.